# Gemfile not found when trying to set up RoR app for digitalocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean

I have followed this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-1-click-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-10-with-digitalocean

and I already ran into a wall..

I have followed the tutorial and installed all the gems, however I keep on getting this whenever I try to bundle install :

```
root@montrealfixed:~# bundle install 
Bundler::GemfileNotFound 
Here is the output of tail /home/unicorn/log/unicorn.log 
I, [2013-11-01T16:37:37.842833 #3929] INFO -- : worker=0 spawning... 
I, [2013-11-01T16:37:37.845118 #3929] INFO -- : worker=1 spawning... 
I, [2013-11-01T16:37:37.847094 #3929] INFO -- : master process ready 
I, [2013-11-01T16:37:37.852229 #3932] INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=3932 

I, [2013-11-01T16:37:37.859884 #3934] INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=3934 

I, [2013-11-01T16:37:37.869478 #3932] INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list 

I, [2013-11-01T16:37:37.876426 #3934] INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list 

I, [2013-11-01T16:37:41.489375 #3934] INFO -- : worker=1 ready 

I, [2013-11-01T16:37:41.490536 #3932] INFO -- : worker=0 ready 

96.127.229.50 - - [01/Nov/2013 16:38:35] "GET /rails.png HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.4569
```

I even tried refreshing unicorn.

I'm not sure if this is appropriate for a ticket, but can anyone help me ? I would really like to get my rails app launched with DO.

P.S : I tried again and installed every gem separately and now i am simply getting the following :

```
-bash: bundle: command not found
```

Comment: `Bundler::GemfileNotFound` makes me think you were not executing `bundle install` from the correct directory (should be root of your rails application) - `-bash: bundle: command not found` you could try fully qualifying the path to bundler? sometimes the best thing is to spin up a new box and start fresh - a quick scan of that article: "Unicorn is used to serve Ruby on Rails applications and looks for files in /home/rails." so you would need to upload your source code to that directory and bundle from there as well

Comment: Thanks. figured it out, thanks for putting me on the right track!